# How to get DataGrid Horizontal Scrolled size?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to drop some content to a DataGrid, dropped content must be mapped to the column over dropped was performed.

To do that I set my **Datagrid.AllowDrop = true**   and calculating the column using it's width property.

```
private void DGrdDatosImportar_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var dropPos = e.GetPosition(DGrdDatosImportar);
    double RefPos = DGrdDatosImportar.RowHeaderActualWidth;
    DataGridColumn SelecteCol = null;
    foreach (DataGridColumn Col in DGrdDatosImportar.Columns.ToList())
    {
        double ColWidth = Col.ActualWidth;
        if (dropPos.X >= RefPos && dropPos.X <= (RefPos + ColWidth))
        {
            SelecteCol = Col;
            break;
        }
        RefPos += ColWidth;
    }

    if (SelecteCol != null)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("IImportProperty"))
        {
            ImportColumn ImpCol = (ImportColumn)SelecteCol;
            IImportProperty prop = e.Data.GetData("IImportProperty") as IImportProperty;
            Importar source = ((Importar)GrdMain.DataContext);
            source.EmparecarColumna2Excel(prop, ImpCol.ColParms);
        }
    }
}
```

It works great when all the columns fits on my screen, but when horizontal scroll is performed it fails.

I was Searching for any property on my Datagrid that allow me to get the horizontal scroll performed but can't found anything, same at each column but nothing :(

How Can I do to get the amount of **horizontal scroll** performed in my DataGrid ?

There is another approach to Get the column where my drop was performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Can I do to get the amount of horizontal scroll performed in my DataGrid ?

You could use the `VisualTreeHelper` class to get a reference to the `DataGrid`'s `ScrollViewer` element and then access its `HorizontalOffset` property:

```
private void DGrdDatosImportar_Drop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ScrollViewer sv = GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(DGrdDatosImportar);
    if (sv != null)
    {
        double horizontalOffset = sv.HorizontalOffset;
        //...
    }
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```